# Highstock print size

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to use the print() function on a Highstock chart, but its not printing well when my chart is very large (almost full screen, for example  1800x1000 pixels),

The problem is that it prints over multiple pages, and also most part of the right half of the chart gets cut off...

Is there a way to resize the chart before printing (but not resize on screen), or is there some sort of "scale to fit page" functionality?

Basically I just want it to look nice on a4 / letter paper format.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the exporting parameters [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting). You can specify `scale` and `sourceWidth` and `sourceHeight`. As for "look nice" you will have to play around with the sizes until you reach this subjective goal.

Comment: I tried to specify these parameters, but unfortunately they only apply to the exporting functionality (Save as PNG, JPEG, PDF), and not to printing. I think these parameters are sent to the highcharts exporting server.

Comment: For now, i'm resizing my chart first with chart.setSize(), to 1000x600 pixels. Then when i call chart.print(), everything looks good. But i think it depends on the DPI of the screen or printer? After printing i resize my chart back to the old dimensions...

Comment: Correct. The larger you make the chart in dimension the more likely you are to see artifacts and "banding" depending on the quality of the printer. I think the parameters do affect printing - at least I can find no mention that they do not. How are you printing? Are you using the built-in HighCharts print button or are you using some other method?